# How can I create a QCloseEvent for a widget created by the mainwindow

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, widget

My MainWindow creates a QWidget called wid. How can I create a slot that is activated when that widget is closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subclass the QWidget and add the functionality as follows:

```
class CloseableWidget: public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    CloseableWidget(QWidget* parent = nullptr): QWidget(parent) {}
signals:
    void onClose(QCloseEvent* e);
protected:
    void closeEvent(QCloseEvent* e) override {
        emit onClose(e);
    }
};
```

and create instance of `CloseableWidget` instead of `QWidget`, Now you can connect your `wid` with `onClose` signal with a slot of MainWindow.

Comment: Do I need to include it separately? i am getting these errors:  C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '*'    error: C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

Comment: The pointer declaration is: CloseableWidget *wid=new CloseableWidget;

Comment: Add this in seprate header file for the `moc`

Comment: I just put the closeWidget class after the mainwindow class and was trying to create a pointer to closewidget in the declaration of mainwindow. But now it works, thank you!